# Node-sass script does no longer work and I can't find the reason why

Tags: sass, node-modules

I can no longer use my compile:sass script

"  "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w" " because I receive error as soon as I run it. It did work fine before I restarted Visual Studio Code. I only changed the main folder name from Natours-1 to Natours_1 so my creative cloud folder could sync, but that shouldn't be an issue right?

I am just starting out learning sass and node so this might be a noob question!

I already tried reinstalling sass and checked the package.json and main.scss for flaws which I didn't find!

**Error message:**

```
> node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w

/Users/basgroep/Creative Cloud Files/Development/1_Natours/node_modules/scss-tokenizer/lib/tokenize.js:265
                if (ident.test(css) && (ident.lastIndex = pos || 1) && ident.exec(css).index === pos) {
                                                                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of null
    at tokenize (/Users/basgroep/Creative Cloud Files/Development/1_Natours/node_modules/scss-tokenizer/lib/tokenize.js:265:87)
    at Object.scss.tokenize (/Users/basgroep/Creative Cloud Files/Development/1_Natours/node_modules/scss-tokenizer/lib/entry.js:18:35)
    at parseImports (/Users/basgroep/Creative Cloud Files/Development/1_Natours/node_modules/sass-graph/parse-imports.js:4:26)
    at Graph.addFile (/Users/basgroep/Creative Cloud Files/Development/1_Natours/node_modules/sass-graph/sass-graph.js:69:17)
    at Graph.addFile (/Users/basgroep/Creative Cloud Files/Development/1_Natours/node_modules/sass-graph/sass-graph.js:81:12)
    at Object.module.exports.parseFile (/Users/basgroep/Creative Cloud Files/Development/1_Natours/node_modules/sass-graph/sass-graph.js:146:11)
    at Object.watcher.reset (/Users/basgroep/Creative Cloud Files/Development/1_Natours/node_modules/node-sass/lib/watcher.js:19:21)
    at watch (/Users/basgroep/Creative Cloud Files/Development/1_Natours/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass:260:20)
    at run (/Users/basgroep/Creative Cloud Files/Development/1_Natours/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass:319:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/basgroep/Creative Cloud Files/Development/1_Natours/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass:405:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! natours@1.0.0 compile:sass: `node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the natours@1.0.0 compile:sass script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/basgroep/.npm/_logs/2019-09-02T08_57_21_368Z-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below command

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```